# Querying hierarchical structure in RavenDB

Tags: indexing, ravendb

I've a category hierarchy saved in a single document in RavenDB.

```
"CategoryList": [
{
  "$id": "1",
  "Id": "Admin",
  "Name": "Administration",
  "ParentCategory": null,
  "Subcategories": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "Id": "Admin1",
      "Name": "Administration 1",
      "ParentCategory": {
        "$ref": "1"
      },
      "Subcategories": []
    },...
```

I can load it successfully in C# using these two classes

```
public class Categories
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Category> CategoryList{ get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]
public class Category
{
    private readonly IList<Category> _subcategories;

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Category> Subcategories
    {
        get { return _subcategories; }
    }

    public Category()
    {
        _subcategories = new List<Category>();
    }

    public void AddSubcategory(Category subcategory)
    {
        subcategory.ParentCategory = this;
        _subcategories.Add(subcategory);
    }
}
```

But now I would like to query my category hierarchy to retrieve a single category by its Id. How could I do that? Would it be better to create one document per category?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Hi, Ayende,

Thanks for the reply. I believe the way `Hierarchy` method is being used in your article is obsolete, but I was able to find the new version...

After reading this [article](http://daniellang.net/using-an-index-as-a-materialized-view-in-ravendb/), I've created an index returning all categories:

```
public class CategoriesByIdIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Categories, CategoriesByIdIndex.ReduceResult>
{
    public class ReduceResult
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }
    }

    public CategoriesByIdIndex()
    {
        Map = categoriesCollection => from categories in categoriesCollection
                                      from category in categories.CategoryList
                                      from subcategory in category.Hierarchy(x => x.Subcategories)
                                      select new
                                                 {
                                                     subcategory.Id,
                                                     Category = subcategory
                                                 };

        Store(x => x.Id, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Store(x => x.Category, FieldStorage.Yes);
    }
}
```

When I do this query, all categories are returned:

```
var allCategories = session.Query<Categories, CategoriesByIdIndex>()
            .AsProjection<CategoriesByIdIndex.ReduceResult>()
            .ToList();
```

But when I try to filter it by a category Id, I receive an empty list:

```
var singleCategory = session.Query<Categories, CategoriesByIdIndex>()
            .AsProjection<CategoriesByIdIndex.ReduceResult>()
            .Where(x => x.Id == "Admin1")
            .ToList();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks